# Titanium TiCollectionView not compiling on device

Tags: uicollectionview, titanium, appcelerator-titanium, native-module

I am using
- ti.CollectionView version 3.0.1
- Ti SDK 7.5.0
- iOS version 12.2

On simulator everything compiles nicely and the module works perfectly
But compiling to the device renders the following error:

```
[ERROR] ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] The following build commands failed:
[ERROR]         Ld [PATH]/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/[APPNAME].build/Debug-iphoneos/[APPNAME].build/Objects-normal/armv7/[APPNAME] normal armv7
[ERROR] (1 failure)
```

Has anyone had this error before ?
I have absolutely no clue as to how to fix this issue

Comment: can you please run it with `--log-level trace` output? There might be an error above that line that points to the problem (e.g. https://github.com/nuno/TiCollectionView/issues/86)

Comment: Well unfortunately I didn't get any more detailed info with trace but after adding 'Ti.UI.createRefreshControl()' the collectionView seems to be working ...
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thank to @miga I was able to get the collectionView working by adding Ti.UI.createRefreshControl() to the code.
Seems that the collection view needs these elements to be created